# What do time subqueries do in MetricsQL? [time1:time2]

Tags: prometheus, victoriametrics, metricsql

I consistently go back and forth on whether the time subquery [12h:5m] is updating the calculation every five minutes or it is calculating every 15 seconds but looking at points 5 minutes apart instead of 15s, so 144 points instead of 2880.

When I look at this query it appears to be doing both. The 15 second values on the time series are updating every 5 minute, but the count is also scalling down to looking at 12 hour points every 5 minutes.

`count_le_over_time(metric[12h:5m], 1)`

This appears to be counting how many points out of 144 (12h, 5m interval) are less than 1. But it is also repeating that number every 15 seconds for 5 minutes.

`count_le_over_time(metric[12h:5m], 1)`

I expect how many points out of 144 are less than one, updating every 15 seconds.

What I see is how many points are less than 1 out of 144 repeating every 15 seconds and updating the count every 5 minutes.

Another example could be

`avg_over_time(metric[12h:5m])` Is this calculating the average of 144 points over 12 hours or is it calculating the average of 2880 points and updating it every 5 minutes?

Comment: It seems you are a bit confused about `step` and `resolution`. 15s you've mentioned is a step: how often query is executed, and how often points will be shown on your graph. `resolution` (5m in your examples) affect how and how much samples for aggregation are taken. More details on resolution in the linked question.

Comment: The examples of the queries in the initial post need to make more sense. Subqueries are needed to apply functions to results of rollup expressions. In other words, to calculate nested rollup expressions. For example, for expression `max_over_time(rate(http_requests_total[5m])[1h:30s])` the inner function rate(http_requests_total[5m]) is calculated with step=30s.
See more at https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#subqueries
and https://valyala.medium.com/prometheus-subqueries-in-victoriametrics-9b1492b720b3